# How to pass a parameter to a function from a button in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

The Button class has a function parameter. But the function is triggered only if no parameter is passed. When trying to pass a parameter to a function, I get - **TypeError error: 'NoneType' object is not callable.**

Here is an example, when I try to pass the parameter **'S'** to the **'Sample'** function, I get an error.

```
import pygame
import sys


pygame.init()

W, H = 800, 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 30


class Button:
    def __init__(self, button_text, width, height, x, y, onclick_function=None, one_press=False):
        self.button_text = button_text
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.onclick_function = onclick_function
        self.one_press = one_press
        self.already_pressed = False

        self.fillColors = {
            'normal': '#ffffff',
            'hover': '#666666',
            'pressed': '#333333',
        }
        self.button_surface = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.button_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

        self.button_surf = font1.render(button_text, True, (20, 20, 20))

    def draw(self):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.button_surface.fill(self.fillColors['normal'])
        if self.button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.button_surface.fill(self.fillColors['hover'])
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed(num_buttons=3)[0]:
                self.button_surface.fill(self.fillColors['pressed'])
                if self.one_press:
                    self.onclick_function()
                elif not self.already_pressed:
                    self.onclick_function()
                    self.already_pressed = True
            else:
                self.already_pressed = False
        self.button_surface.blit(self.button_surf, [
            self.button_rect.width / 2 - self.button_surf.get_rect().width / 2,
            self.button_rect.height / 2 - self.button_surf.get_rect().height / 2
        ])
        display.blit(self.button_surface, self.button_rect)


def sample(g):
    print(g)


s = 15
btn = Button('Button', 200, 50, 300, 250, sample(s))


while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    display.fill('blue')
    btn.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Everything works if I don't pass parameters from the button to the function. But I need to do it somehow.

Comment: When you construct the Button instance the 6th parameter will be the return value from *sample(s)*. You could use a *partial* for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sample(s)` immediately calls `sample` with the parameter `s` and the return value of the function (`None`) is passed to the `Button` constructor. You need to pass a function object to the constructor. Use a [Lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expression:

<s>`btn = Button('Button', 200, 50, 300, 250, sample(s))`</s>

```py
btn = Button('Button', 200, 50, 300, 250, lambda: sample(s))
```